# Ruby best practice: working with classes

Tags: ruby

See the example below, i suppose it is best to use the second method but the first also works.
Which method is best and what are the consquences of using the other ?

```
class Test 
  def start 
    p "started"
  end
  test = Test.new 
  test.start 
end 

class Test2
  def start 
    p "started"
  end
end
test2 = Test2.new 
test2.start
```

Comment: Instead of `test2 = Test.new` you probably meant `test2 = Test2.new`.

Comment: Depends. Do you want to automatically have an instance of your class assigned to a variable you probably already use in your code when you load your class?

Comment: you'r right LukaD, a typo, corrected it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this any number of ways, it's up to you. Here is a fun one...

```
class Test 
  def start 
    p "started"
  end
  new 
end.start
```

More seriously, your first example encapsulates everything in the one class. That's ok, for a script; it puts everything in your own namespace and mostly avoids the mysterious main object context. You can define nested classes if you need them.

However, the second approach is more conventional.

Comment: Sure, you *could* do this any number of ways, but why would you ever do this in practice? The OP is asking about best practices and if I ever saw someone writing code like this, I would strongly discourage it. It's unconventional and hard to read, plus if you rearrange the order of how things are declared within the class, it breaks.

Comment: @Beerlington Just curious, why would it break? Do you mean rearranging the `new`? Because the final `.start` after the class should continue to work.

Comment: Clever code nominates new design patterns for consideration and once familiar they cease to be hard to read. Shorter code is ultimately *easier* to read. Yes, some people find only simple code easy, but automatically disparaging fun code goes against the specifically stated goal of Ruby's inventor. Fun IS authorized in Ruby. There are other languages if you want boring. And in some ways, this example *is* simple.

Comment: @emboss If you would define the method start after `new` a new object would be created and start would be called on it before start was even defined.

Comment: @LukaD OK, I understand now, it's about rearranging the `new`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would say definitely the second variant makes much more sense. The first will not cause an error, but the object instantiation is totally obsolete and meaningless. Outside variables are not visible within the class's scope:

```
var = "string"

class A
  var = A.new
end

puts var #=> string
```

There's no closure, the outer `var` is different from that within the class. This means your object "gets lost" after creation and won't be accessible anymore, and eventually be subject to GC.

When you say that the first example "works", working in this context means that it *is* possible to call a method on a newly created object right after creating that object in the class scope. But it is not possible to hold that object as a reference for later use (without assigning it to class (instance) variables).

If you need no reference for later use, and you really want to do such a "one shot" operation, it would be more idiomatic to either use a class method that can be called without instantiating an object or to do what's necessary in the `initialize`, if it's something that has to be done on each instantiation.

Answer (score 3):

Defining a class that creates an object of itself when it's load is not a good idea.
The object would only be available to itself and not to it's parent's scope (of course you could still access it via [`ObjectSpace::each_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-each_object)).

Comment: True, but the OP is probably writing a script, which would explain the immediate need for an object. I think either one is OK in that case.

Comment: i'm writing a simple script most of the time and i guess a module would be more appropriated here but i saw the first way used and wondered if it makes a difference

Answer (score 2):

#### Some Best Practices for Ruby Classes

- Use a consistent structure in your class definitions.
- Don't nest multi line classes within classes. Try to have such nested classes each in their own file in a folder named like the containing class.
- Prefer modules to classes with only class methods. Classes should be used only when it makes sense to create instances out of them.
- Favor the use of module_function over extend self when you want to turn a module's instance methods into class methods.
- When designing class hierarchies make sure that they conform to the Liskov Substitution Principle.
- Try to make your classes as `SOLID` as possible.
- Always supply a proper `to_s` method for classes that represent domain objects.
- Use the attr family of functions to define trivial accessors or mutators.
- Avoid the use of `attr`. Use `attr_reader` and `attr_accessor` instead.
- Consider using `Struct.new`, which defines the trivial accessors, constructor and comparison operators for you.
- Don't extend an instance initialized by `Struct.new`. Extending it introduces a superfluous class level and may also introduce weird errors if the file is required multiple times.
- Consider adding factory methods to provide additional sensible ways to create instances of a particular class.
- Prefer duck-typing over inheritance.
- Avoid the usage of class `(@@)` variables due to their "nasty" behavior in inheritance.
- Assign proper visibility levels to methods (private, protected) in accordance with their intended usage. Don't go off leaving everything public (which is the default). After all we're coding in Ruby now, not in Python.
- Indent the `public`, `protected`, and `private` methods as much as the method definitions they apply to. Leave one blank line above the visibility modifier and one blank line below in order to emphasize that it applies to all methods below it.
- Use def self.method to define class methods. This makes the code easier to refactor since the class name is not repeated.

This is the best doc for best practises in ruby: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide